# Check if answer in next row is different based on a condition python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
country  question    year   value
   1      a1          2017     Y
   1      a1          2018     Y
   1      a1          2019     N
   1      a2          2017     N
   1      a2          2018     N
   1      a2          2019     Y
   2      a1          2017     Y
   2      a1          2018     Nan
   2      a1          2019     Y
   2      a2          2017     Y
   2      a2          2018     N
   2      a2          2019     Y
   3      a1          2017     Y
   3      a1          2018     N
   3      a1          2019     Y
   3      a2          2017     Y
   3      a2          2018     Y
   3      a2          2019     Y
```

I want to find where the value from the previous year does not match the value from the next year. I have tried using shift but it doesn't give me what I want.
This is how far I've gotten:

```
 country = all_data['country']
 question = all_data['question']
 value = all_data['value']

 for i in range(len(country)):
     if(country[i] == country[i+1] && question[i] == question[i+1]):
```

Thank you for any suggestions!!

Comment: there's no 'country' column in the sample you shared. Can you also add your desired output so that we have a clearly defined goal?

Comment: sorry, Id was meant to be country

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- do a partial key self-join (`merge()`)
- filter down to rows where year is different by 1 and value is different
- self-join full to dataframe built above to construct column

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("""   id     question    year   value
   1      a1          2017     Y
   1      a1          2018     Y
   1      a1          2019     N
   1     a2          2017     N
   1      a2          2018     N
   1     a2          2019     Y
   2      a1          2017     Y
   2      a1          2018     Nan
   2      a1          2019     Y
   2      a2          2017     Y
   2      a2          2018     N
   2      a2          2019     Y
   3      a1          2017     Y
   3      a1          2018     N
   3      a1          2019     Y
   3      a2          2017     Y
   3      a2          2018     Y
   3      a2          2019     N"""), sep="\s+")

# do a "self-join" to find years where values are different to previous year
dfdiff = df.merge(df, on=["id","question"], 
         suffixes=("","_pre")).loc[lambda dfa: dfa.year.eq(dfa.year_pre+1) 
                                   & dfa.value.ne(dfa.value_pre)]
# from knowing id, q, year where different construct another column "changed"
df.merge(dfdiff.loc[:,["id","question","year"]].assign(changed=True),
         on=["id","question","year"], how="left").assign(changed=lambda dfa: dfa.changed.fillna(False))
```

|  | id | question | year | value | changed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | a1 | 2017 | Y | False |
| 1 | 1 | a1 | 2018 | Y | False |
| 2 | 1 | a1 | 2019 | N | True |
| 3 | 1 | a2 | 2017 | N | False |
| 4 | 1 | a2 | 2018 | N | False |
| 5 | 1 | a2 | 2019 | Y | True |
| 6 | 2 | a1 | 2017 | Y | False |
| 7 | 2 | a1 | 2018 | Nan | True |
| 8 | 2 | a1 | 2019 | Y | True |
| 9 | 2 | a2 | 2017 | Y | False |
| 10 | 2 | a2 | 2018 | N | True |
| 11 | 2 | a2 | 2019 | Y | True |
| 12 | 3 | a1 | 2017 | Y | False |
| 13 | 3 | a1 | 2018 | N | True |
| 14 | 3 | a1 | 2019 | Y | True |
| 15 | 3 | a2 | 2017 | Y | False |
| 16 | 3 | a2 | 2018 | Y | False |
| 17 | 3 | a2 | 2019 | N | True |